# How can I sort, filter and tag files/images in Android ICS 4.0?

Tags: photos, images, search

**A little background**

Im a bit into graphic design, digital painting etc, and I like to draw on the run, away from my desktop. For drawing, I often need reference materials - some pictures of things I would like to draw. While drawing/designing a futuristic car, Id like to be able to look at pictures of some modern cars, planes, helicopters, materials etc.

Looking for reference on the Internet on my android tablet is cumbersome, and I dont have Internet access everywhere. I do have a big library of reference pictures on my SD card tho.

I cant really use it as reference yet, because looking manually for pictures of things I want to draw is a LOT of work. Designign something, say a cyborg, Id have to dig through the files searching for "human", "metal", "machine" and "mechanism" pictures.

**So, what do I want?**

I would like to tag and sort for pictures/files with tags similar to those I mentioned ("human", "machine", "engine" etc), but i dont want to upload it anywhere or use it online. I dont want to share and want to keep it local, usable without Internet access.

If I could display all the chosen pictures on one screen, it would be a big bonus.

How could I do that on my Android tablet? I'm using ICS 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

As long as pictures/videos are involved, you might want to take a look at [Monte Gallery](http://www.appbrain.com/app/monte-gallery-image-viewer/kr.co.itfs.gallery.droid). This app offers you a.o. the feature to add descriptions *and tags* to pictures, and then lets you browse them by tags. It also offers browsing by location, and (as you can see by the screenshots on its market page), a nice "calendar view", grouping pictures by "date taken". Only thing missing is to combine those using a search mask, like "show me all pictures tagged *foobar* taken between [dates] on [location]" :)